# Anyway meaning and usage

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> "I am going to leave, anyway"

What does *anyway* means here
And how to use *anyway* in a sentence

Answer (score 2):

> "I am going to leave, anyway."

The meaning of "anyway" in a sentence like this one depends in part on the context, and on the prior sentence in the discussion. Consider:

> "Get out of my house, and never come back!"

vs.:

> "Are you leaving just because Real Madrid is losing by two goals?"

I could answer either one with:

> *I was going to leave anyway*.

---

In the first case, that means:

> I don't need you to kick me out. I was going to leave **whether you planned to kick me out, or planned to  let me stay**.

In the second case, it means:

> I'm not leaving because Real Madrid is losing. **I needed to leave at this time no matter what**, because...

The "because" part could be anything, such as:

- because I need to go get Jimmy at the airport in 20 minutes.
- because I promised Michelle I'd be home before 9 o'clock.
- because I need to go walk the dog before he chews up the couch.

Comment: This should not be confused with the two word *any way* which means *any method or manner.*